# Real numbers is $T_0$ or not with the given topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the real numbers set. Given the topology
$\tau=\{U\subseteq\mathbb{R} : \text{ either } 0\in U \text{ or } 1\notin U\}$,  is $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ a $T_0$ space?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I thought of that I can not find any open set which contains 0 and does not contain 1 according to definition of topology, but for example is [1/2,3/2] open?

Comment: The set $\{0\}$ is open which contains $0$ but not $1$ in this topology.

Comment: Can we say that {0} is open? According to topology, I guess just one of the condition must be satisfied , if it contains zero and does not contain 1, it is not open I guess, either or issue ? For example I think [0,1) is not open to this topology, it satisfies both of conditions ? @absolute0

Comment: @Etü "Or" is meant *inclusively* by default in mathematics. Things like $\{0\}$ and $[0,1)$ *are* open in this topology.

Comment: @NoahSchweber thank you for the feedback :)